# how to add brand name with image at facebook page share content

Tags: wordpress

Sometimes we see some page post on my timeline, where website shareing link conatin a image, below part of image attach with a page brand name (i have atatch a image example below.). if you click on link you will go to the website page and you will not see the brand name with image. I think somehow this brand name added later by coding or other system. I am confirm, content uploader does not attach this brand name with image, it happen automaticaly.

there anyone please tell me the system nmae and how to do it? at word press how can do that? have any plugin or code? thanks in advance.

[image: this is my example attach image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the meta property inside the header area of ​​your site. Please check below article to know more.

[For Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/)
[For Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/guides/getting-started)

You can add meta properties like this.

```
add_action('wp_head','add_meta_tags');
function add_meta_tags() {
  global $post;
  echo '<meta property="og:title" content="'.$post->post_title.'" />';

  // So on....
}
```

Comment: I am not problem with title actually. I have marked red, that is not part of actual image, but it showed on afcebook share link. how can we add this brand name without add it manually. thanks

Comment: It must be part of image.
They are showing a image different on a article and they are passing different image on social media.
You can verify it from that site og:image meta property, view-source that page to show.

Comment: thanks @Bipin, I know that what are you talk about. But I can assure you uploader does not do anything with image. S/he just uplad one image to server, that's all thing he done and rest of things happend by program. I want to know that, anybody here who use this code and know how to do.